# Android Fibonacci Benchmark / Deep recursion

Tags: java, javascript, android, benchmarking, fibonacci

I'm running a Fibonacci benchmark on my Android phone and I'm getting some strange results. As I don't really care if the UI-thread is locked or not, I'm running the code below inside the UI-thread in my application (could this affect the performance btw?).

```
public void startBenchmark(View view) {
        results = "";

        results += String.format("Begin test");
        for (int i = 45; i < 46; i++) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            fib(i);
            results += String.format("%d\n", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
        results += String.format("End test");
        Log.d("Results", results);


    Log.d("Status", "Finished");
}

private static int fib(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

I've also implemented the corresponding code in JavaScript;

```
function performBenchmark() {

    for (var i = 45; i < 46; i++) {
        benchmark(i)
    }

}

function benchmark(n){
    var start= Date.now();
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML += "fib(" + n + "): " + fib(n) + " <br />";
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += (Date.now() - start) + "<br />";

}

function fib(n) {
    return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

My problem is that for fib(45) I get something like 420 seconds on the native platform using Java and 120 seconds using Javascript in Chrome, both running on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Is there something blatantly wrong with my implementation in Java for Android that could be slowing down the benchmark?

NOTE; **I'm not primarily looking to switch to a faster algorithm but I'm trying to understand why Javascript (and also an implementation I made for iOS) is much faster than the implementation in Java for Android.**

Running on my laptop I get much faster results for Java than for Javascript.

Comment: I replicated your results on Nexus 7. Java is 3-4 times slower than JS. I guess it is something about the memory management implementation.

Comment: @yoah; sad-face, but thanks for testing. Any thoughts are still appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at logcat, maybe you see heavy GC or similar

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to compare very, very inefficient code.  When you do you are comparing very specific optimisations the languages do which give you little indication which a different program might do.

---

Your solution is very slow in Java and JavaScript.  Some languages are smart enough to re-write your code more efficiently (e.g. functional languages) but neither Java nor JavaScript will re-organise you code to be more efficient.

```
private static int fib(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Think about this, to get a solution of 1134903170, you need to call this method more than this many times (to get down to 1 and all the calls down to those values)

Note: each solution takes exponentially longer and is proportional to the solution.

I suggest you use iteration which is much faster in Java and JavaScript.

```
private static long fib(int n) {
    long a = 1, b = 1;
    while (--n > 1) {
        long c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Note: the time this take is proportional to the value of `n`, in this case 45.

Note 2: this solution is so short, the code doesn't even warmup and get compiled by the JIT.

```
public static void main(String... ignore) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        long fib = 0, start = System.nanoTime();

        int repeats = 2000;
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
            fib = fib(45);
        long avgTime = (System.nanoTime() - start) / repeats;

        System.out.println(fib + " took an average of " + avgTime + " nano-seconds");
    }
}
```

prints

```
1134903170 took an average of 2695 nano-seconds
1134903170 took an average of 995 nano-seconds
1134903170 took an average of 90 nano-seconds
1134903170 took an average of 89 nano-seconds
1134903170 took an average of 89 nano-seconds
```

Note 3: The 89 nano-seconds is ~4 billion times faster, which cannot be explained by using a faster machine.

Comment: Did you all of my post? "I'm not primarily looking to switch to a faster algorithm but I'm trying to understand why Javascript (and also an implementation I made for iOS) is much faster than the implementation in Java for Android."

Comment: @Poyan Did you read by first paragraph? "It doesn't make sense to compare very, very inefficient code. When you do you are comparing very specific optimisations the languages do which give you little indication which a different program might do."

Answer (score 0):

Java-Code gets executed 5 times, JavaScript only once.

Comment: My bad, I didn't remove that part. However, the 420 s was for a single call to fib(45) and I've edited the code to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Maybe there is not enough RAM and the system starts to swap out to secondary memory? How do the results change if you compute fib(18) in both cases?

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately, JavaScript is till multiple times faster.